# form update in tag table just post first id

Tags: laravel

sorry if my english bad but you know about it?

```
<td class="shoping__cart__quantity">
     <div class="quantity">
       <form id="update-keranjang" action="{{ route('UpdateKeranjang') }}" method="post">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="pro-qty">
        <input type="text" name="keranjang" value="{{ $p->qty }}" required>
        <input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $p->id}}" hidden>
       </div>
       </form>
     </div>
</td>
```

i want to update my qty in view laravel but if i click my  tag.

```
<td class="shoping__cart__item__close">
      <a style="color: black; margin-right: 20px" class="fa fa-refresh" href="{{ route('UpdateKeranjang') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('update-keranjang').submit();"></a>
</td>
```

it post a first row, i have two row in table view and if i click second row it post a first row. how can i post my second row to get the id??

Thank you for answer this question.

i want to get the id of second row if i clicked the second tag.

Comment: Most likely you have duplicate `id="update-keranjang"` - which is invalid. Why not use a submit button to submit the forms?

Comment: thank you my problem solve. i try to add id in id="update-keranjang{{$id}}" to make a different id. thank you